# Segmentation fault on call to `gdk_rgba_to_string()`

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gtk, gtk3

I tried to convert `GdkRGBA` to a `gchar *` with the function `gdk_rgba_to_string()`. For instance:

```
GdkRGBA *color_01;
gchar *color_string = gdk_rgba_to_string(color_01);
```

In my code, this one gives segmentation fault, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code crashes because you need to allocate memory to a pointer, or to allocate the structure in automatic or static memory, for example

```
GdkRGBA color = {0};
gchar *color_as_string = gdk_rgba_to_string(&color);
```

Comment: That's a subtle one! Thanks man, this was a majestic. I'll remember that for sure.

Comment: Just as a note, you guys meant GdkRGBA instead of GtkRGBA. I'll edit both question and answer. Thanks